# How to avoid duplicating code in cond clause LISP?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am supposed to find the path from the root to a given node in LISP. Preferably using a purely functional approach.

The binary tree representation uses sublists, e.g.: 
`(A (B) (C (D) (E)))` - A is the root, B the left child of A, C the right child of A, D the left child of C and E the right child of C.

It seems to me that there should be some way to avoid the duplication of the following function calls:

`(get-path (cadr l) x)`

`(get-path (caddr l) x)`

I am new to LISP and I don't know and can't seem to find a solution for this, but I think there must be a -purely- functional way to do it. Maybe using lambdas? Not sure how, though. Am I using a wrong approach? Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

```
;;; l is the list with the binary tree
;;; x is the node we are looking for
(defun get-path(l x) 
    (cond
            ;; nothing to search for anymore
            ((null l) nil)
            ;; found the node we were looking for
            ;; in this case we return a list containing only x
            ((equal (car l) x) (list x))
            ;; the node was found on the left branch
            ((not(equal (get-path (cadr l) x) nil))
                     (cons (car l) (get-path (cadr l) x)))
            ;; the node was found on the right branch
            ((not(equal (get-path (caddr l) x) nil))
                     (cons (car l) (get-path (caddr l) x)))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd combine the final two cond clauses.  You want to check the left side and see if there's a path there, and if there is, take it, and if there's not, check the right side.  Then, whichever one of those yielded a path (if either did), you want to append to that.  That could look like this. First, a couple of functions for convenience:

```
(defun element (tree)
  (first tree))

(defun left (tree)
  (second tree))

(defun right (tree)
  (third tree))
```

Now, the real meat of the solution:

```
(defun get-path (element tree)
  (cond
    ;;  A null tree is empty and doesn't match anything.
    ((null tree) '())
    ;; If the element of this tree is the element, then we have a
    ;; partial path of length 1: (ELEMENT).
    ((eql element (element tree)) (list element))
    ;; Othweise, let PATH be the path on the left or the path on the
    ;; right, whichever exists.
    (t (let ((path (or (get-path element (left tree))
                       (get-path element (right tree)))))
         ;; If there's no path on either side, then return NIL.
         ;; Otherwise, prepend the current element onto the path that
         ;; exists.
         (if (null path) '()
             (list* (element tree) path))))))
```

Note that **list*** does the same thing as **cons**, but it makes it clearer that you're working with *lists*, not just *cons cells*.  You could use **cons** just as well.

We can confirm that this works as expected:

```
(defparameter *tree* '(A (B) (C (D) (E))))

(get-path 'c *tree*) ;;=> (A C)
(get-path 'd *tree*) ;;=> (A C D)
(get-path 'f *tree*) ;;=> NIL
```

Comment: You could easily encapsulate element, left and right using labels to avoid polluting the cl-user namespace. The OP was about eliminating duplicate code, not refactoring the entire solution.

Comment: @scottm definitely.  This is a small enough amount of code that I don't think that a small amount of refactoring for readability (which might help op or other readers) will keep OP from being able to apply this technique.  The refactoring is just a bonus.

Answer (score 4):

What about this?

```
(defun root-path (tree element)
  (when tree
    (cons (first tree)
          (unless (eql (first tree) element)
            (or (root-path (second tree) element)
                (root-path (third tree) element)
                (return-from root-path nil))))))
```

You should even define meaningfully named functions, like `tree-value` `left-subtree` and `right-subtree`, but this is maybe overkill here.

In the above, note that `when` (resp. `unless`) is used for its `nil` value when the condition fails (resp. succeed). You can translate with `cond` or `if` expressions if you prefer. The only repetition here is the double `(first tree)` value, which might be optimized away by the compiler or manually with a surrounding `let` binding.

#### Edit

The original code was not working. The solution is to use Joshua's answer, but I won't copy paste it here, so I added the `return-from` expression. While it works, your teacher and/or coworker will probably *not* like this approach ;-)

#### Tests

```
(mapcar (lambda (n) (root-path '(A (B) (C (D) (E))) n))
        '(a b c d e f))

=> ((a) (a b) (a c) (a c d) (a c e) nil)
```

Comment: Pay attention that it does not work. Try it with `(root-path '(A (B) (C (D) (E))) 'D)`.

Comment: @Renzo Thanks. I "fixed" it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use `labels` for interior (local) functions:

```
(defun get-path(l x)
    (labels ((prepend-path (elt)
                (cons (car l) (get-path elt x))))
        (cond
            ;; nothing to search for anymore
            ((null l) nil)
            ;; found the node we were looking for
            ;; in this case we return a list containing only x
            ((equal (car l) x) (list x))
            ;; the node was found on the left branch
            ((not(equal (get-path (cadr l) x) nil))
                     (prepend-path (cadr l)))
            ;; the node was found on the right branch
            ((not(equal (get-path (caddr l) x) nil))
                     (prepend-path (caddr l))))))
```

Alternatively, you could use `flet` instead of `labels` because you don't have interior functions that refer to each other. Personally, I use `labels` and hardly ever use `flet` for that reason (plus the overhead of re-indenting the function.)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is replicate the anaphoric [`conda`](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-025CC33C) and [`ifa`](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-018F39B0) macros from TXR Lisp in Common Lisp. (Source code here; good luck!)[enter link description here](http://www.kylheku.com/cgit/txr/tree/share/txr/stdlib/ifa.tl)

Then you can write it like this, referring to the `get-path` expressions using the anaphoric `it` variable.

```
(conda
  ;; nothing to search for anymore
  ((null l) nil)
  ;; found the node we were looking for
  ;; in this case we return a list containing only x
  ((equal (car l) x) (list x))
  ;; the node was found on the left branch
  ((not (equal (get-path (cadr l) x) nil)) (cons (car l) it))
  ;; the node was found on the right branch
  ((not (equal (get-path (caddr l) x) nil)) (cons (car l) it)))
```

`conda` is clever about expressions of the form `(not x)` and `(null x)` (also `(false x)` in TXR Lisp). If the test expression is one of these, then it recurses into the `x` do ferret out the "anaphoric `it`".

Note that `it` binds to **places** not just to **values**. Not only is the target of `it` not evaluated more than once, if the target is a place, then `it` refers to that place:

```
(ifa (< x 10)
  (inc it)) ;; increments x.
```

This aspect of `ifa` is achieved with the help of the [`placelet`](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-0393C970) macro, which doesn't exist in Common Lisp.  A quick and dirty substitute would be to use `symbol-macrolet`. The only problem is that that a symbol macro denoting a place allows multiple evaluation of the place whereas `placelet` evaluates a place once. The resulting lexical symbol then denotes the storage location, rather than the overall expression.

`ifa` was designed to either wipe the floor with Paul Graham's `aif`, or else to complement it; `conda` is trivially based on `ifa`.

By the way, do not write expressions like

```
(not (equal whatever nil))
```

in Lisp!  Firstly, `equal` equality is not particularly meaningful if you are comparing with `nil`; only `nil` is `equal` to `nil`, and that is according to `eq` equality, so you might as well have:

```
(not (eq whatever nil))
```

Secondly, for something not to be `eq` to nil means that the something is true.  That is to say:

```
(if (not (eq foo nil)) do-this)   ---same-as--> (if foo do-this)
```

!

If we refactor your code to get rid of this stuff, then it's better if we have the Paul Graham Style anaphoric if `aif` (and an `acond` based on it). That is to say:

```
(ifa (not (equal (get-path whatever) nil))) (list it))
```

becomes:

```
(aif (get-path whatever) (list it))
```

where the `it` trivially to the value of the entire test expression, rather than a somewhat cleverly selected constituent of that expression.

Under `ifa`, this is expressed slightly more verbosely using:

```
(ifa (true (get-path whatever)) (list it))
```

Where `true` can be defined as

```
(defun true (x) (identity x)).
```

Without this extra wrapping, `ifa` will bind `it` to `whatever`.